# Someone has files from my Mac on their external hard drive

Tags: terminal, mac, logs

I have my housemate's old Mac. He still has an account on it, neither of us have each others passwords so we cannot access each others accounts, and public file sharing is turned off (and I don't keep files there anyway).

He let me borrow his external hard drive to back up some files temporarily, however I noticed that on this drive (which he also uses to back his files up), there were photos and videos from my account - it was like my photo stream had been backed up to his hard drive. These were in a folder called 'archive'.

I have tried checking terminal for logs etc but am finding it hard to get anywhere, as the 'last' command returns no results for his account. Is it possible that my photos and videos are somehow backing up to his computer or drives? It was quite disturbing seeing my photos and videos there already...and in a folder that had clearly been created and not just copied (as I don't actually have a single folder on my Mac for photos etc.). He created the accounts I have for me so I'm wondering if he has done something there...

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you set up a backup at any point?

Comment: No, I've never set up a backup.

Comment: If I found my stuff on that external « taken » that I had not put there, then I would either delete it or failing that, wipe the drive totally... of course he could have a copy somewhere else...

Comment: Yeah it's more how they got there in the first place...I'm worried that my Mac isn't secure but I can't for the life of me work our why that might be - I change my password monthly etc.

Comment: Who of you has admin rights on this Mac?

Comment: That's a good point, we both have admin rights...

Comment: Well then both of you have full access to all files on that machine. Perhaps your housemate took a backup and it included all data as backups should do not just his. Only solution is to have your own machine with only those you trust having admin privilege